# rappid/jointjs - How do I change attributes on a rect.clone()

Tags: jointjs, rappid

I am new to Rappid and Jointjs and I am struggling with syntax/context.
For my first experiment, I simply want to loop over a counter and create a number of rectangles. On each new rectangle I'd like to change the text but whatever I try I can't seem to get it to change the text.
My code is below - thanks for any help.

```js
My Rectangle test
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="joint.css" />
    <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/lodash/index.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/graphlib/dist/graphlib.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/dagre/dist/dagre.core.js"></script>

    <script src="../build/rappid.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="joint.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myholder"></div>
  <div id="myholder-small"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#myholder'),
        width: 600,
        height: 800,
        model: graph,
        gridSize: 1
    });
   

    var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 10, y: 30 },
        size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
        attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, 
                 text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } 
               }
    });
    
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

     var rect2 = rect.clone();
     rect2.translate(10,  (50 * i) );
     rect2.attrs = { rect: {fill:'red'},
                  text: { text: 'Node ' + i } };

  graph.addCells([rect2]);
    
    };

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the attributes via [`element.attr()`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Element.prototype.attr) method.

```js
My Rectangle test
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="joint.css" />
    <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/lodash/index.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/graphlib/dist/graphlib.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/dagre/dist/dagre.core.js"></script>

    <script src="../build/rappid.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="joint.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myholder"></div>
  <div id="myholder-small"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#myholder'),
        width: 600,
        height: 800,
        model: graph,
        gridSize: 1
    });
   

    var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 10, y: 30 },
        size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
        attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, 
                 text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } 
               }
    });
    
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

     var rect2 = rect.clone();
     rect2.translate(10,  (50 * i) );
        rect2.attr({
          rect: { fill:'red' },
          text: { text: 'Node ' + i }
        });

        graph.addCells([rect2]);
    
    };

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```